# Can we extract information from resume in pdf form through coding?

Tags: javascript, pdf-reader

I am curious to know Can we extract Information from any resume that is in pfd format through coading. I know that we can extract text from pdf , there are lots of libraries available but Suppose I want to extract qualification from resume so how will we know how much text we have to split.I hope you guys got my problem. Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing special about a resume, it's just another pdf document.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yeah I know it is just pdf but my problem is how can we extract information from it as there are different types of resumes in the market.

Comment: It isn't really clear what's special about resumes that you think requires special or different methods or tools.  You want to extract text from a pdf.  Just use any tool or service that does that.  If you're looking for a product recommendation, that's off-topic here, but you can ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Upvote for s/w recommendations, which is often the answer to question on this site. In fact, there is a [current active question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2656/a-free-software-cv-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-parser) asking for a free solution. I also have a need for this, and since the "parse resume" is just part of my proposed app (I expect to make money from the rest of the app), I am quite willing to pay for an off-the-shelf solution, as parsing freeform text can be very tricky.

Comment: did you find a solution to extract?  I have the same problem.